# Error during installation of latest stable Chrome on Debian

Tags: debian, chrome

I am trying to install latest, stable Chrome on Debian and get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator3-1 but it is not installable
                        Recommends: libu2f-udev but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am running the following version of Debian:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie
```

I have already used

```
 apt-get update
```

followed by

```
 apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but get the same error during Chrome installation.

Strange thing is that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is empty.

Any idea how to get this installed?

Answer (score 1):

try and update to debian 9 stetch then install chromium form the debian repositories

Answer (score 1):

when you install chrome, skype or any.deb and you encounter this problem just run "apt install -f"

```
sudo apt install -f
```

this will fix the problem or remove the broken package if no chance.

Comment: In this particular case when the distribution is no longer supported on an OS, the -f cannot resolve the problem.   %sudo apt-get install -f google-chrome-stable
...(part of the output copy-paste here) 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libu2f-udev but it is not installable

Answer (score 1):

To install google chrome on debian jessie through the package manager `apt`, you should have the following lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main

deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

then add the signing key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Install google-chrome:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

The package [`libu2f-udev`](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ibu2f-udev) is a *Recommends* dependencies only available for debian buster/Sid.

The [`libappindicator3-1`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libappindicator3-1) package will be installed through `apt` as dependency.

Comment: Strange thing is that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is empty. Why would that be?

Comment: @TitusQuinn I think during the system install `apt` isn't configured correctly. (without internet connection or the apt configuration is skipped)

Answer (score 0):

switch to sudo `sudo su`

1- edit apt sources `cd /etc/apt` https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

2- open it manually `nautilus .` (Backup sources.list)

3- edit sources.list to the complete one

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

4- do  `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` after adding the sources to sources.list

5- exit sudo `with`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

it's work for me and I hope it work for you OR

```
sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and delete these packages in this file